# Vim jumps to last occurence of replacement argument

Tags: vim

When I execute a replace command, e.g

```
:%s/toBeReplaced/Replacement/g
```

Vim jumps to the last occurence of `toBeReplaced`. This is quite irritating because I have to go back to the position where I was editing. I've quikly renamed my .vimrc to .vimrc_ in order to disable my personal .vimrc. The same thing happens, hence it seems to be vim's default behavior.

When a replacement command is executed, I want vim to stick at the position where I am editing at that moment. Is there any way to achieve this??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after you executed the `:s`, press :

```
``
```

will bring you back to the position before your run the cmd.